# hide / show angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller and two directives with templates 
when i start i want to show only one directive.
once a button is clicked i want to switch visibility 
hide the first one and show the second.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])

app.controller('customersCtrl',   function($scope, $http,$uibModal)
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.names=[];
        vm.selected= null;
        vm.id = 0;
        vm.name = "Green Raven";
        vm.grade=93;
        vm.subject="avi's roast";
        vm.date=new Date();
        vm.enableModal=false;

        // paging
        vm.currentPage = 0;
        vm.pageSize = 3;

        vm.load=function ()
        {
            $http.get('Data/todo.json').success(function(data) {
                vm.names = data;
                for (var i=0;i< vm.names.length;i++)
                {
                    vm.names[i].date= new Date();
                }
                vm.id =vm.names.length;
            });
        }
        vm.numberOfPages=function()
        {
            return Math.ceil(vm.names.length/vm.pageSize);
        };

        // selection
        vm.selUser=function(x){

            vm.selected =vm.getName(x);
        };
        ///

        vm.RecalcIndex =function()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.names.length; i++)
            {
                vm.names[i].id = i;
            }
            //customerService.RecalcIndex(vm.names);
        };


        vm.edit=function(id)
        {
            var selectedName= vm.getName(id);
            vm.subject=selectedName.subject;
            vm.date=selectedName.date;
            vm.id=selectedName.id;
            vm.grade=selectedName.grade;
            vm.name=selectedName.name;
        };
        vm.save=function(id)
        {
           // var currentName ={date:vm.date,grade:vm.grade,id:vm.id,name:vm.name,subject:vm.subject};

            for(var i= 0;i<vm.names.length;i++)
            {
                if(vm.names[i].id==id)
                {
                    vm.names[i].date=vm.date;
                    vm.names[i].grade=vm.grade;
                    vm.names[i].id=vm.id;
                    vm.names[i].name=vm.name;
                    vm.names[i].subject=vm.subject;
                    vm.selected=null;
                }

            }
            vm.RecalcIndex();
            vm.modalInstance.close();
        };
        vm.Add = function()
        {
            vm.names.push({name:vm.name,id:vm.id,subject:vm.subject,date:vm.date,grade:vm.grade});
            vm.id += 1;
           // $uibModal.close();
        };




        vm.getName =function(id)
        {
            for(var i =0; i<vm.names.length ;i++)
            {
                if (vm.names[i].id==id) return vm.names[i];
            }
            return null;
         //   return getName(id);

        };
        vm.Remove = function()
        {
            // we dont have a selected row and so we cant continue
            if(vm.selected==null) return;
            vm.names.splice(vm.selected.id, 1);
            vm.selected= null;
            vm.RecalcIndex();
            vm.currentPage = 0;
            vm.id = vm.names.length;
        };


    });


app.directive('newStudent',  function()
{
    return {
        templateUrl:'./myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'newStudentCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'modal',
        scope:{}
    };
});
app.directive('myStudent',  function()
    {
        return {
            templateUrl:'./tmp.html',
            controller: 'customersCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            scope:{}
        };
    });
```

on the html page i put a ng-show=true for the first directive and ng-show =false for the second but for some reason only the first directive is affected by the ng-show

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl as ctrl">
        <div my-Student ng-show="!(enableModal)"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl as ctrl">
        <div new-student ng-show="enableModal"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is `<div my-Student` or `<div my-student` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using controller as syntax so you need to use ctrl.enableModal rather than directly using enableModal in your template.
and the directive name should be like my-student instead of my-Student. :)

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl as ctrl">
        <div my-student ng-show="!(ctrl.enableModal)"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl as ctrl">
        <div new-student ng-show="ctrl.enableModal"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: changed it as u said . it shows both templates although one has ng-show false and the other is true

Comment: Can you create a plunker for this?

Comment: i am not so familiar with plunker i put my files there and i am getting 404 error but cant seem to figure how to debug it